# Mac Mini sometimes doesn't wake DisplayPort monitor

Tags: mac, display, hdmi, displayport, mini-displayport

**Setup:** I'm using a ASUS PB278QR (via thunderbolt to mini dp cable) with a 1080p monitor from acer (via hdmi) on a late 2012 mac mini. The thunderbolt to mini dp cable I'm using is from amazon and not an apple cable.

**Issue:** For some reason, the computer sometimes fails to send a signal to the ASUS monitor when first trying to wake the computer up or turning it on.

**Temporary solutions that sometimes work:**

- Sometimes sleeping the computer and waking it up again fixes it, sometimes it doesn't.
- Sometimes plugging the hdmi cable into the ASUS from the acer, having it send a signal via hdmi and then plugging the cable back into the acer fixes it, sometimes it doesn't.
- Sometimes plugging the hdmi into the ASUS, having the computer send a signal to it via hdmi, switching the signal to dp, unplugging the hdmi and then plugging the hdmi back into the acer fixes it, sometimes it doesn't

**A potential pernament solution that I don't know how to do:**

[Non-Apple monitor with DisplayPort not recognized by a Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/684163/non-apple-monitor-with-displayport-not-recognized-by-a-mac) implies that switching the monitor to using dp 1.1 might fix it but I'm not sure how to do this as I can't find this setting anywhere in the display's menu

**EDIT:** When this happens, it's not that the monitor isn't detected by the computer it's that a signal isn't being sent to it

Comment: I assume you have tried a different cable from a different vendor?  While in general all cables are created there are exceptions to this rule  Most of the time those exceptions apply to Apple products.

Comment: No because I'm not sure whether it would be the cable. I feel like it's more likely the computer or monitor as none of my temporary solutions involve the cable and the monitor does usually work. I realise your next suggestion would now be trying a different monitor and computer but I don't have another dp monitor or computer on hand to use

Comment: I have the same issue with the new Mac Mini, Dell IPS monitor, and C2G Mini-DP to DP cable.  I had three of these setups, and they all had the problem with different amounts of inconsistency.  I ended giving up on Thunderbolt and using a HDMI to DisplayPort cable, which has resolved the issue.  I realize this doesn't help for a dual monitor setup, but I thought you'd like to know you're not the only one.